Setting Schema Registry Proxy URL and Port
We want to configure a Proxy only for the Schema Registry. That means the Proxy muss not be used by the Broker connection.
I'm trying to follow the configuration options for the Schema Registry added in this pull request: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/pull/1144, a few years ago, following this stackoverflow link: How can I tell KafkaAvroSerializer that the connection to the Schema Registry must be through a proxy?
I'm also following the documentation for Schema Registry properties given here:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/installation/config.html
I added the configuration in the Kafka Configuration Class:
props.put("proxy.url", "xxxx") where xxxx is the URL for the proxy.
Something similar for the port.
After, of course, come the producer factory configuration and the Kafka Template.
However, the configurations are not taken when the Schema Regestry is contacted. The connection goes as the proxy doesn't exist.
Can somebody help?

I found the solution. I was using proxy.url instead of proxy.host, that is the right configuration property

The problem was using the wrong property. The right property is proxy.host instead of proxy.url.
